# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Android - big array

Tags: android, arrays, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm new to Android development, please help me with my error.

I'm reading a wav file and processing to compare with the other wav file. I'm getting OutOfMemoryError and assuming it may be due to the big array.
Here is my processing() method:

```
public void processing2(){
    System.out.println("reading in the file  .... ");
    float[] arr1 = readWav1("sink1.wav");
    float[] arr2 = readWav1("think1.wav");
    System.out.println("arr1 size: "+arr1.length);
    System.out.println("arr2 size: "+arr2.length);

    System.out.println("preprocessing .... ");
    FeatureVector a = extractFeatureFromExtractedAmplitureByteArray(arr1);
    FeatureVector b = extractFeatureFromExtractedAmplitureByteArray(arr2);

    System.out.println("vector a num of frames: " + a.getNoOfFrames());
    System.out.println("vector b num of frames: "+b.getNoOfFrames());

    //converting to 1d array
    flattened1 = twoDimToOne(a.getFeatureVector());
    flattened2 = twoDimToOne(b.getFeatureVector());

    System.out.println("1d array1 size: "+flattened1.length);
    System.out.println("1d array2 size: "+flattened2.length);

    System.out.println("DTW .... ");
    d = new DTW(flattened1, flattened2);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

And this is the logcat:

```
System.out: reading in the file  .... 
System.out: File reading in progress..
System.out: File reading in progress..
System.out: arr1 size: 73750
System.out: arr2 size: 65558
System.out: preprocessing .... 
System.out: noOfFrames       110  samplePerFrame     512  EPD length   28556
System.out: noOfFrames       100  samplePerFrame     512  EPD length   25872
System.out: vector a num of frames: 110
System.out: vector b num of frames: 100
System.out: 1d array1 size: 4290
System.out: 1d array2 size: 3900
System.out: DTW .... 
dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 131.007MB to 128.000MB
dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 134.938MB to 128.000MB
dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 31216-byte allocation
dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 134.938MB to 128.000MB
dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 31216-byte allocation.
…
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native Method)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Below is the one way you can avoid OOM issue. But if you worked with low ram like 512 then this will also not worked so better to better approach of comparing wav file without having big array.

Comment: I've added android:largeHeap="true" in manifest, didn't work. Increased heap size manually, also didn't work. 
I'm storing into array, because i need the frequencies. I need to detect how well the person pronounces the word. Could you suggest any solution?

Comment: You can search compare  wav files. You needn't cmpare them byte by byte.

Comment: I think you need some open source voice detect.

Comment: from where you are taking this wav file, from server, from sdcard? if from sdcard then you dont need to take wav file you can have path of the files and process it accordingly.

Comment: Currently i'm just comparing prerecorded wav files which are in assets folder. But what i need to do is to record the word (non-native speaker) which will be stored in SDcard, and compare it against prerecorded wav files (native speaker) which are again in assets.

Answer (score 0):

Add **android:largeHeap="true"** in your manifest.xml Application tag

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Comment: This does not really solves the problem, this is more or less the last resort, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html.